# How do I sort a dictionary without using the sorted function?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

The following code creates a dictionary of each letter in the alphabet and the relative percentage of the text that each letter takes in terms of counts of appearance.

I'm giving it to show the structure of what I'm trying to achieve without using 'sorted' or 'collections' method. For example 
`print({k: v for k, v in sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)})`
works perfect but this is not what is required.

what is required is the same functionality using loops and reordering the items in the dictionary.

Here's the entire code, the item in question starts at `for i in range`:

```
def count_char(text, char):
    count = 0
    for c in text:
        if c == char:
            count += 1
    return count

filename = "newfile.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    text = f.read()
mydict = {}
i = 0
j = 1
y = {}
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for char in alphabet:
    perc = 100 * count_char(text, char) / len(text)
    mydict.update({char: round(perc, 2)})

for i in range(len(alphabet)):
    for j in range(len(alphabet)):
        if list(mydict.values()).index(i) > list(mydict.values()).index(j):
            y.update({'0': dict.values[j]})
            mydict.update({mydict.values([j]): mydict.values([i])})
            mydict.update({mydict.values([i]): y.values([0])})
    j += 1
i += 1
j = i + 1
```

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: Presumably for homework? As such, here's a hint- you don't _have_ to use a dictionary for this, a list of tuples may solve your problem better...

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a sorting algorithm? That's really quite broad, there's tons of stuff on this topic in any undergraduate textbook, or anywhere on the internet, or even on here already...